# Blazor How should I get an `IJSObjectReference` when invoking a js function which may return `null`?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor

For example, I have a module in typescript like:

```js
export function getIndexedDb() : IDBFactory | null
{
    if (window.indexedDB)
        return window.indexedDB;
    else
        return null;
}
```

Now I want to get an `IJSObjectReference` of its result, so I have tried this in csharp:

```cs
await using var module = await jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "xxxx.js");
await using var result = await module.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("getIndexedDb");
```

It works well when there is a `window.indexedDB`, but when `getIndexedDb()` returns `null`, an error will occur:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot create a JSObjectReference from the value 'null'.
```

(And I can't even catch the exception in csharp. The csharp method seems to just stopped here and later codes won't be executed. Is this a bug?)

So what should I do to solve this problem? I don't believe the below one is a good idea:

```js
class Nullable<T>
{
    value: T | null;
    constructor(value: T | null)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
    getValue() : T | null
    {
        return this.value;
    }
    isNull() : boolean
    {
        return this.value === null;
    }
}

export function getIndexedDb() : Nullable<IDBFactory>
{
    if (window.indexedDB)
        return new Nullable<IDBFactory>(window.indexedDB);
    else
        return new Nullable<IDBFactory>(null);
}
```

Comment: what happens if you try `await module.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference?>` , so with nullable type? Otherwise you might need to check if `window.indexedDB` exists in a different method

Comment: @noel Thanks for your advice. However nothing will be changed by a nullable type, since it's just a check at compile time. And adding a different method is way, but it does cause an unnecessary performance overhead, so I'm asking for a better practice.

Comment: Strange that they are supposed to fix this in https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/pull/41916 but I still have the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hardly a solution, but I just worked around this by instead of returning null throwing an exception. This can then be catched on the C# end, and from there return null (or do whatever)

```js
// JS
function getXyz() {
  if (xyz)
    return xyz;
  else
    throw 'xyz does not exist';
}
```

```cs
// C#
public async ValueTask<IJSObjectReference> GetXyz()
{
  try
  {
    return await jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>('getXyz');
  }
  catch
  {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: there still seems to be no better solutions... and i have found a related issue here: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/52070